# Redirect CorDapp logs to a specific logger

Tags: corda

After reading the [documentation on logging](https://docs.corda.net/design/monitoring-management/design.html#custom-logging-for-enhanced-visibility-and-troubleshooting), I understand it is possible to filter by the log emitting class in the following way:

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
</Logger>
```

Is there a way to specify a logger for *an individual CorDapp*, though, without making any assumptions about the log messages emitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really-- Cordapps are designed to be able to be run by many nodes in a large network, and the unified logging service means that each node can decide where they want to send their logs too

That said it's based on Log4j, and you can configure quite a few different log backend options, and you could filter & redirect logs using either custom scripts, or services like Azure Application Insights or Datadog (for example)